# Spring Web Flow Request Mapping not working

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I am trying to test Spring Web Flow and cannot access the flow basing on the mapping I'm using. I'm sure I must be missing something simple, but here is my setup...

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>accommodations</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>accommodations</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
/WEB-INF/datasource-config.xml
/WEB-INF/security-config.xml
/WEB-INF/webflow-config.xml
/WEB-INF/aop-config.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
```

webflow configuration:

```
<flow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows/" >
<flow:flow-location-pattern  value="**/*-flow.xml"/>
</flow:flow-registry>

<flow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
<property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
<property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

The flow xml defination is locations in "WEB-INF/flows/accommodations/accommodations-flow.xml", 
so my understand is that /accommodations should map to the flow.

When I point the browser to /accommodations I receive a 404.

What mistake am I making..?

Comment: Try  /accommodations-flow